# Which webSphere should MobileFirst server runs on?

Tags: amazon-web-services, websphere, ibm-mobilefirst

**What I want to achieve:**

1) Set up MobileFirst Server using Amazon Web Service EC2 (Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS (HVM))

2) MobileFirst version 7.1.

**What I've done:**

According to [this tutorial](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/moving-production/moving-development-environment-stand-alone-qa-production-servers/):

> Installing MobileFirst Server
>   IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation is compatible with the following application servers:
>   WebSphere Application Server full profile,
>   WebSphere Application Server Liberty profile,
>   Apache Tomcat

Hence, I've decided to use the first option which is WebSphere Application Server full profile.

**Problem:**

I don't know where to download the WebSphere Application Server full profile for my case. The only options are these in [IBM partners world](https://www-03.ibm.com/isc/esd/dswdown/dswdown.wss/web/searchDescription), it does not have mobile first 7.1:

[image]

It's rather confusing.

**UPDATED:**

I've tried to do a quick search using this key word: "websphere application server liberty profile" in IBM partners word. Here is the list of results:

[image]

**UPDATE 2:**

I couldn't find "CN6DIML" in the partners world. I can only find it in [IBM Passport Advantage Online](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24040199#IMF_P5):

[image]

1) Is this the correct place to download it?

2) Could you please point me to a installation guide which includes the download for IBM Installation Manager and Installation of Mobile First Server?

3) Is a refresh pack for IBM Installation Manager sufficient?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebSphere Application Server Full Profile is not available in the IBM Partner World for MobileFirst Platform - only the Liberty counter-part. If you require WebSphere Full Profile you need to contact WebSphere directly and *purchase* it.

Comment: Hi @IdanAdar, I've tried to do a quick search using this key word: "websphere application server liberty profile" in IBM partners word (results in the question) , I'm still unclear which one to download. Is 
"IBM WebSphere Application Server Liberty Core with Custom Pattern V8.5.5 Multiplatform Multilingual (CRV3YML)" the correct one to support MobileFirst7.1 and running on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (HVM)?

Comment: You'll want: CN6DIML  IBM WebSphere Application Server - Liberty Core V8.5.5.5 for Multiplatform Multiling

Comment: I couldn't find "CN6DIML" in the partners world. I can only find it in "IBM Passport Advantage Online": http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24040199#IMF_P5 (screenshot in the question update 2 section) is this the correct place to download it? Could you please point me to a installation guide which includes the download for IBM Installation Manager and Installation of Mobile First Server?